# Using @link and @see with Javadocs

Tags: javadoc

I've never really written javadocs and am starting to write them for the local applications at work.  Most of them are Java servlets.  I'm worried that I'm getting a bit too descriptive/complex.

Even I get confused on what all form types are sent from the browser, so I'm trying to include them in the javadoc.

All the servlets have the following custom tag:

```
    tag form.Type:a:"Form types sent from browser:"
```

Here's an example of a javadoc for one processRequest:

```
/**
 * Handles requests from browser.
 * 
 * @param request
 * @param response
 * @throws ServletException
 * @throws IOException
 * @form.Type initial: Calls {@link org.bcso.com.appearancerequest.html.NotifierHTML#getHTML} if
 * credentials are valid<br>
 * submitRequest: Calls {@see #submitRequest(HttpServletRequest request)}<br>
 * afterEdit: Calls {@link org.bcso.com.appearancerequest.html.AdminHTML#getHTML()}<br>
 * getAdmin: Calls {@link org.bcso.com.appearancerequest.html.AdminHTML#getHTML()}<br>
 * getDeputyAdmin: Calls {@link org.bcso.com.appearancerequest.html.DepAdminHTML#getHTML()}<br>
 * deleteDeputy: Calls {@see deleteDeputy(HttpServletRequest request)}<br>
 * saveOrUpdateDeputy: Calls {@see addOrUpdateDeputy(HttpServletRequest request)}<br>
 * getCourtAdmin: Calls {@link org.bcso.com.appearancerequest.html.CourtAdminHTML#getHTML()}<br>
 * saveOrUpdateCourt: Calls {@see addOrUpdateCourt(HttpServletRequest request)}<br>
 * deleteCourt: Calls {@see deleteCourt(HttpServletRequest request)}<br>
 * getReports: Calls the {@link org.bcso.com.appearancerequest.html.ReportsHTML#getHTML()}<br>
 * reportByDate: Calls {@see getReportByDate(HttpServletRequest request)} <br>
 * reportByDeputy: Calls {@see getReportByDeputy(HttpServletRequest request)}<br>
 * reportByRequestor: Calls {@see getReportByRequestor(HttpServletRequest request)}<br>
 * saveNoShow: Saves data concerning a deputy who no-shows via {@link org.bcso.com.appearancerequest.util.DatabaseUtil#saveNoShow(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)} 
 * and generates an email via {@see sendNoShow(int deputyId, int notificationId)} to admin.<br>
 * reviewLogin: Calls {@see #reviewerLogin(Map user)}<br>
 *
 */
```

Am I doing this right?  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I think this amount of doc is not too big. You need to consider its format though, as this format is very different from examples in [How to Write Doc Comments for the Javadoc Tool](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html).

It's not clear the variables from submitRequest and down belong to request, or should be filled in to response. Also {@link} and {@see} in your doc create same effect. I'm not sure why you use one in some places, but other in another places.

Just my observation.